# Updating a column from another's repeatable values

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following table

Invoice

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ InvoiceId + InvoiceDate +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+   int     +     int     +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

InvoiceLine

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ InvoiceLineId +  InvoiceId + InvoiceDate +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+    int        +    int     +    int      +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I recently added the last (InvoiceDate) column to the table and I would like to update it's values with the corresponding values from the Invoice table. For every InvoiceId that matches in both tables, the InvoiceDate should be added to InvoiceLine.

If more input is needed don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Update InvoiceLine
Set InvoiceDate = Invoice.InvoiceDate 
From Invoice inner join InvoiceLine on Invoice.InvoiceId = InvoiceLine.InvoiceId
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this?

```
    update detail
    set invoicedate = summary.invoicedate
    from invoiceline detail 
         inner join invoice summary
             on summary.invoiceid = detail.invoiceid
```